# removing inner div but not its content [fastest way]

Tags: jquery

i have html structure like this

```
<div>
    <span class="ic">
        <span class="ic">12345</span>
     </span>
</div>
```

i want to convert it

```
<div>
    <span class="ic">12345</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/). This method removes the element's parent.

```
$('div .ic .ic').unwrap();
```